# Unterschied zwischen "zutreffend" und "treffend"

Tags: difference

Ich denke, dass die beide Wörter als "richtig", "angemessen" verstanden werden können. Welche Unterschiede gibt es dazwischen? Oder sie können synonym verwendet werden?

Comment: Ich war kurz versucht, die Frage als *off-topic* zu markieren, weil sie durch ein Wörterbuch weitgehend beantwortbar ist. Um das in Zukunft zu vermeiden,  empfehle ich, mehr Substanz in die Frage zu packen, also zu erklären woher die Unklarheit kommt und warum ein ordentliches Wörterbuch nicht weiterhilft.

Answer (score 1):

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl ist da ein kleiner Unterschied:

im Sinne von korrekt:

> Eine Vorhersage trifft zu.

im Sinne von hilfreich oder akkurat:

> Eine Beschreibung oder Vergleich ist treffend.

In vielen Fällen ist der Unterschied marginal und sie können und werden synonym genutzt.

Answer (score 0):

Nur, weil es eine Überlappung in der Bedeutung gibt, also sich in **manchen** Fällen die gleiche Bedeutung ergibt, heißt natürlich **nicht**, dass es in **allen** Fällen so ist; ich betrachte die Überlappung zwischen *treffend* und *zutreffend* als ziemlich klein. Für die angegebene Bedeutung  *angemessen* fällt mir kein zündendes Beispiel ein.

Ein wesentlicher Unterschied:

- *Zutreffend* ist ein digitale Aussage: entweder trifft etwas zu oder nicht. Nach meinen Krimi-Kenntnissen wird es deshalb auch gerne in den Befragungen von Staatsanwälten verwendet. ("Ist es zutreffend, dass Sie...")
- *Treffend* gibt es in Abstufungen; die Charakterisierung einer Person oder Tätigkeit kann unterschiedlich gut ausfallen; wenn sie ziemlich gut ist, nennt man sie *treffend*.